# Paypal standard HTML company image missing

Tags: html, paypal, cart

I'm using (I think) the standard Paypal checkout, with a bit of HTML to specify the product details. In the past, [the "image_url" variable](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables) specified a company banner to display at the top of the Paypal cart. It is now no longer showing [after I click Add](https://www.sis-group.org.uk/order.htm).

- I note the banner size has changed from 900x150 down to 150x50, which
  I have now modified.
- I have made the image available by https

Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the documentation of PayPal where it says

> The URL of the 150x50-pixel image displayed as your logo in the upper left corner of the PayPal checkout pages. 
>   Default — Your business name, if you have a PayPal Business account, or your email address, if you have PayPal Premier or Personal account.

Found it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables). The banner only takes up approximately 150x50 pixel

Comment: Yes, I reduced the banner size. I now find that the image does appear on the Checkout/Payment page, but it does not appear on the Shopping Cart page. It would be nice to show it there too.